# Splitting large data set and plotting the average in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a large data set with over 10,000 rows with values between 0 and 400,000,000.  I would like to plot those values vs. the mean of another column in matplotlib where the x axis increments by 50,000,000 but I am unsure how to do so.  I can plot it using pandas but would really like to do it using matplotlib but unsure how.  This is what I have in pandas:

```
mean_values = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['budget_adj'],np.arange(0,4000000000,50000000)))['vote_average'].mean()
mean_values.plot(kind='line',figsize=(12,5))
```

Comment: what is your problem? What is not working? What kind of plot do you use in matplotlib? A scatter plot with `plt.scatter()`? You can adjust your x-axis with `xticks`/`set_xticks`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out what your problem is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Create some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'budget_adj': np.random.uniform(0, 4000000000, 10000),
                   'vote_average': np.random.uniform(0, 100000, 10000)})

# Calculate the mean values
mean_values = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['budget_adj'],np.arange(0,4000000000,50000000)))['vote_average'].mean()
```

And this is what I suspect you do

```
# This wont work since mean_values.index is an interval
plt.plot(mean_values.index, mean_values)
```

This wont work since you index is a categorical interval. In order for `plot` to work your x-values have to be numbers. We can convert our intervals in many ways

```
# You can pick the left endpoint...
x_values = [i.left for i in mean_values.index]
# the right endpoint...
x_values = [i.right for i in mean_values.index]
# or the center value.
x_values = [i.mid for i in mean_values.index]

# And NOW you will get no error
plt.plot(x_values, mean_values)
```

Comment: I did try that but kept getting an error I couldn't figure out how to solve.  When I try that I get IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: If you can provide some sample data and an example reproducing your error  it is a lot easier to try to help.